# GetMapping "produces" works even though doesn't match accept header

Tags: spring, request-mapping, get-mapping

### Intro

There is a `@GetMapping` attribute, as the following in one of our projects:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/", produces = SaConstants.SA_MEDIA_TYPE)
public HttpEntity<Resource<Home>> get(HttpServletResponse response) {
```

In the SaConstants class:

```
public static final String SA_MEDIA_TYPE="application/sa+json";
```

When I access the page from any internet browser, I am getting the proper response that I want - and my breakpoint in the controller is being triggered.

The browser is sending the following headers:

```
Host: 127.0.0.1:8001
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.104 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: io=Qt74kp5V5ziUNIxlAAAG
```

When I make a request to the page, without an `Accept` header, the page is not working.

If I add to postman the following Accept header, everything works:

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
```

### Question

My question are:

- why does it work even if the `Accept:` header of the request doesn't match the `produces` attribute of the Rest Controller?
- Why does it fail if no Accept header is provided (given the first question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*/*" means all types, this header is by default provided by most of the popular browsers